# React tutorial - firefox has error when loading data in array

Tags: reactjs

I'm following the tutorial at:
http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html

I get the following  error in the Firefox developer tools console:

SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'  tutorial.js:4:3

The browser window does not show anything. I am under the impression from the tutorial that I should be seeing the information given in the data array at the bottom of the JS file. I am opening the index.html file as a local file (not running a server). Why won't this work?

My project is as follows:

```js
var Comment = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
  return (
   <div className="comment">
    <h2 className="commentAuthor">
     {this.props.author}
    </h2>
     {this.props.children}
   </div>
  );
 }
});
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
  return (
   <div className="commentBox">
    <h1>Comments</h1>
    <CommentList data={this.props.data} />
    <CommentForm />
   </div>
  );
 }
});

var CommentList = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
  var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(comment) {
   return (
    <Comment author={comment.author}>
     {comment.text}
    </Comment>
   );
  });
  return (
   <div className="commentList">
    {commentNodes}
   </div>
  );
 }
});

var CommentForm = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
  return (
   <div className="commentForm">
    Hello, world! I am a CommentForm.
   </div>
  );
 }
});


React.render(
 <CommentBox data={data} />,
 document.getElementById("content")
);

var data = [
 {author: "Pete Hunt", text: "This is one comment"},
 {author: "Jordan Walke", text: "This is another comment"}
];
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Hello React</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.0/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.0/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="content"></div>
  
   <script src="scripts/tutorial.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `type="text/jsx"` to your script element for `tutorial.js`.

```
<script type="text/jsx" src="scripts/tutorial.js"></script>
```

---

**Update**

For the TypeError, that's because you declared your data after you had already tried to render. Swap the order of these two lines:

```
React.render(
    <CommentBox data={data} />,
    document.getElementById("content")
);

var data = [
    {author: "Pete Hunt", text: "This is one comment"},
    {author: "Jordan Walke", text: "This is another comment"}
];
```

to this:

```
var data = [
    {author: "Pete Hunt", text: "This is one comment"},
    {author: "Jordan Walke", text: "This is another comment"}
];

React.render(
    <CommentBox data={data} />,
    document.getElementById("content")
);
```

Comment: I am now receiving a TypeError: this.props.data is undefined index.html:27:8

Comment: I updated my answer with a fix for the other error you were seeing